# How to center div below other element, not parent div?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Here's an image showing what I'm trying to achieve:

[image]

As you can see, I'm trying to get the profile options dropdown to be centered below the profile button. The current way I have it set up is to have the dropdown menu have `position: absolute`, and then use a `margin-left: -3%` to actually "center" it, but I feel like there should be a more reliable way to actually center it that isn't dependent on a hardcoded percentage value. Below is the relevant code:

index.php:

```
<div id="navTools">
    <button id="navProfile"><img src="./imgs/profile.svg" alt="Profile"/></button>
    <div id="profileDropdown">
        <a href="#example">Account Information</a>
        <a href="#example">Orders & Returns</a>
        <a href="./logout.php">Logout</a>
    </div>
    <a id="navCart" href="cart.php"><img src="./imgs/cart.svg" alt="Cart"/></a>
</div>
```

styles.css

```
#profileDropdown {
  display: none;
  background: #1d1d1d;
  position: fixed;
  margin-left: -3%;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Wrap profile button and profile dropdown in a div. Give that div `position: relative` and set `position: absolute` for the dropdown. If you want it to appear at the bottom, set `bottom: 0`. If you want to center it vertically, set `left: 50%, transform: translateX(-50%)`.

```
<div id="navTools">
<div class="dropdown-wrapper">
    <button id="navProfile"><img src="./imgs/profile.svg" alt="Profile"/></button>
    <div id="profileDropdown">
        <a href="#example">Account Information</a>
        <a href="#example">Orders & Returns</a>
        <a href="./logout.php">Logout</a>
    </div>
</div>
<a id="navCart" href="cart.php"><img src="./imgs/cart.svg" alt="Cart"/></a>
```

```
.dropdown-wrapper {
    position: relative;
}

#profileDropdown {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
}
```